# Best way to repeat an equation with its numerical tag unchanged, without affecting the numbering of other equations

Tags: beamer, counters

In a presentation, when I talk about a previous equation, I think it is better to repeat it than just referencing it. My equations in beamer are numbered. So, I want repeat equation (4.9) after equation (4.12), and then continue the numbering normally:

```
equation    (4.11)
equation    (4.12)
equation    (4.9)
equation    (4.13)
equation    (4.14)
```

What is the best way to do it?

Code sample:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\newtheorem{remark}{Observação}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Norma e medida angular usando produto escalar}
\begin{itemize}
  \item De posse do produto escalar, agora as fórmulas para a norma e para a medida angular podem ser escritas da seguinte maneira:
      \begin{equation}\label{E:NormaProdEscalar}
        \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}},
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{E:CosAngProdEscalar}
        \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{u}\rVert\lVert\vec{v}\rVert}.
      \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Definição geométrica de produto escalar}
\begin{remark}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Nós definimos o produto escalar algebricamente, num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal, mas ele também pode ser definido geometricamente, sem coordenadas, pela equação~\eqref{E:CosAngProdEscalar}:
          \begin{equation}\label{E:ProdEscalarGeom}
            \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} = \lVert\vec{u}\rVert\lVert\vec{v}\rVert \cos \theta,
          \end{equation}
          onde $\theta = \mathrm{ang}(\vec{u},\vec{v})$.
    \item Mas atenção: embora não seja necessário um sistema de coordenadas ortogonal para definirmos produto escalar, a fórmula
    \begin{equation}\label{E:ProdEscalarCoord2}
    (u_1, \dots, u_n)\cdot(v_1, \dots, v_n) = u_1v_1 + \dots + u_nv_n,
    \end{equation}
    \emph{só pode ser usada num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal}.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Definição geométrica de produto escalar}
\addtocounter{remark}{-1}
\begin{remark}
(Continuação)
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]\addtocounter{enumi}{2}
    \item O mesmo vale para norma: ela pode ser definida geometricamente, sem coordenadas, aproveitando uma definição geométrica prévia do produto escalar:
       \begin{equation}
       \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}, \tag{1}
       \end{equation}
       mas a fórmula
       \begin{equation}\label{E:NormaCoord2}
       \lVert(v_1, \dots, v_n)\rVert = \sqrt{v_1^2 + \dots + v_n^2},
       \end{equation}
       \emph{só pode ser usada num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Notice I used `tag{1}` to repeat the number of a previous equation. This is not a good way to repeat a previous value of a counter, because that value may change, say to 2, and if this happens, I would have to change manually `tag{1}` to `tag{2}`.

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]

Comment: Could you include some code please? You are leaving it up to the people you want help from to do literally everything from `\documentclass{beamer}` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Ok, I will provide.

Comment: Do you want to repeat just the equation or the whole frame with the equation?

Comment: Just the equation.

Comment: Now I have provided the code sample.

Comment: If you are a bit flexible with the syntax, you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459508/how-can-i-repeat-a-formula-without-copying-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\tag{\ref{E:NormaProdEscalar}}` to avoid the hard coded equation number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\newtheorem{remark}{Observação}

\usepackage{thm-restate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Norma e medida angular usando produto escalar}
\begin{itemize}
  \item De posse do produto escalar, agora as fórmulas para a norma e para a medida angular podem ser escritas da seguinte maneira:
      \begin{equation}\label{E:NormaProdEscalar}
        \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}},
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{E:CosAngProdEscalar}
        \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{u}\rVert\lVert\vec{v}\rVert}.
      \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Definição geométrica de produto escalar}
\begin{remark}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Nós definimos o produto escalar algebricamente, num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal, mas ele também pode ser definido geometricamente, sem coordenadas, pela equação~\eqref{E:CosAngProdEscalar}:
          \begin{equation}\label{E:ProdEscalarGeom}
            \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} = \lVert\vec{u}\rVert\lVert\vec{v}\rVert \cos \theta,
          \end{equation}
          onde $\theta = \mathrm{ang}(\vec{u},\vec{v})$.
    \item Mas atenção: embora não seja necessário um sistema de coordenadas ortogonal para definirmos produto escalar, a fórmula
    \begin{equation}\label{E:ProdEscalarCoord2}
    (u_1, \dots, u_n)\cdot(v_1, \dots, v_n) = u_1v_1 + \dots + u_nv_n,
    \end{equation}
    \emph{só pode ser usada num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal}.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Definição geométrica de produto escalar}
\addtocounter{remark}{-1}
\begin{remark}
(Continuação)
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]\addtocounter{enumi}{1}
    \item O mesmo vale para norma: ela pode ser definida geometricamente, sem coordenadas, aproveitando uma definição geométrica prévia do produto escalar:
       \begin{equation}
       \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}, \tag{\ref{E:NormaProdEscalar}}
       \end{equation}
       mas a fórmula
       \begin{equation}\label{E:NormaCoord2}
       \lVert(v_1, \dots, v_n)\rVert = \sqrt{v_1^2 + \dots + v_n^2},
       \end{equation}
       \emph{só pode ser usada num sistema de coordenadas ortogonal.}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Very simple. Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoAlvesJr. You're welcome!